# Install and use pdfcrop on windows

Tags: pdfcrop

first of all I have to admit I'm definitely not an expext with tex stuffes ; I have found several post related to perl script not working with latex but I can't figure out what is happening on my computer.

So, I try to use pdfcrop `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop`. I downloaded the pdfrcrop.pl file but the documentation for windows was pretty blurry to me.

I have been able to run perl pdfcrop.pl and now I have :

- MikTex\miktex\bin\x64\pdfcrop.exe
- MikTex\scrips\pdfcrop\pdfcrop.pl
- MikTex\tex\latex\scrips\pdfcrop\pdfcrop.pl

When I type in the command prompt:

- pdfcrop --version, I get: `pdfcrop 2012/11/02 v1.38`
- perl --version, I get `This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 <v5.22.0> ...`

Now I am using pdfcrop through knitr and I get the error message :

```
cropping figure/pyfig.pdf
pdfcrop: The Perl interpreter could not be found.
```

When I try to run directely pdfcrop in the Terminal, it stops at the second steps:

```
*Copy input file to temporary file
!!!Error copy failed, <No such file or directory/Access denied>
```

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: It is included in MikTeX. Use the package manager to install it.

Comment: when running the package manager, it says it is already installed

Answer (score 4):

You need first to install Perl support for Windows (for example https://www.activestate.com/activeperl) and after that use Miktex package manager to install pdfcrop.

Then you should be able to use command `pdfcrop` on Windows Powershell or Command prompt.

Comment: Is there a way that does not require me to make an account?

Comment: @JonasSchwarz use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing on Windows with [TinyTex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/):

```
Rscript -e "tinytex::tlmgr_install('pdfcrop')"
```